# How to break ( if ) under function in php

Tags: php

i am beginner and learn to code on php, i create simple code to make sure input is not integer. How should i do it?

```
<?php 

function paint($room="office",$color="red")
{
if ($room=integer)
    {
    echo "Cannot input number"; break;
    }
else;
return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}

echo paint();
echo paint("bedroom","blue");
echo paint("kitchen",null);
echo paint(2,4);  //i want to give message "cannot input number"
?>
```

Comment: You have some syntax error here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php. Working code : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f29ec11699dd676bfb1c716f95244673ff8c922

Comment: You cannot break if statements but return from function inside if blocks.

Comment: You might want to check out the [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function - and when you `return` a function you break out of it anyway so you could probably reduce the content of that function to `return is_numeric($room) ? "Cannot input number" : "The color of the {$room} is {$color}.";`

Comment: Use `is_int($room)` when checking for integer type, however you say: 'Cannot input *number*'.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit a function, just use a `return;` statement. In your case however, you can just add the code in the `else` part of your if statement.

```
if (is_numeric($room)) {
    echo "Cannot input number"; break;
} else {
    return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

Or with return statement:

```
function paint($room = "office", $color = "red")
{
    if (is_numeric($room)) {
        echo "Cannot input number";
        return;
    }

    return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

---

**Update:**
If you want the code execution to stop and show a message, the best thing you can do is throw an exception.

```
function paint($room = "office", $color = "red")
{
    if (is_numeric($room)) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot input number");
    }

    return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

Comment: This is `break` but `return` or nothing, fatal error - break not in loop.

Comment: If you want to stop the execution and show a message, you should throw an exception. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thanks guys, i just learn how to code, i will definitely look into this :D

Comment: It works! i've changed the $room=int into is_numeric($room), then add return after echo. But i am curious why i cannot use $room=int, but is_numeric($room) works? what is the different on both?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the above answers can lead you to a solution.
So here an other kind of answer.

Best Practice: Try to be consistent with types.

Think about what your function should return.
In your case you want a `string` to be returned.

The easiest solution is that one:

```
<?php

function paint($room="office",$color="red")
{
    if (is_numeric($room))
    {
        // It is an integer (e.g. 1)
        // or it is a float (e.g. 3.141)
        return "\ncannot input number");
    }

    if ($room === null) {
        // You may have to check for null, too
        return "\ncannot input null");
    }

    // or potentially any other "Type" a user can pass in.

    return "\nthe color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

The return inside of the `if`-condition is called "Early return" and can help you keeping your code simple.

You're now **always returning a `string`**.

In newer PHP Versions it it`s possible to use the "type system".
You want wo *enforce* your function to accept  only string arguments.

This can be expressed like that:

```
<?php 

function paint(string $room="office",string $color="red"): string {
    return "\nthe color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}

echo paint() // => the color of the office is red.<br />
echo paint(1) // => the color of the 1 is red.<br />
```

See the "types" here?
at the moment this produces some strange behaviour. `paint(1)` "works".

This is because php "casts" the `1` to a `"1"`. We don't want this in this case.

You can add `declare(strict_types=1);` at **the beginning** of you `.php`-File.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

function paint(string $room="office",string $color="red"): string
{
    return "\nthe color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}


echo paint(); // => the color of the office is red.<br />
echo paint(1); // => Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to paint() must be of the type string, integer given
```

You now have a clear error message and you must pass a string to the function.
It's easy to understand and you removed many edge-cases. E.g. `is_int` does not work with `1.22` (`float`).

Sorry for the long answer :-)
But i wanted to show you a "more modern/robust" solution to your problem.

Comment: well noted sir! will try to be consistent with types

Comment: tried using if ($room === null) does not work, however, using is_null($room) is working fine, thanks for the insight :D

Answer (score 0):

In the above program, you have used the **break** statement without any looping or switch statement and for checking the variable whether it is an integer or not you have used `integer` which is wrong. use the function `is_int(<varname>)` returns `boolean`.

The PHP parser throws an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  'break' not in the 'loop' or 'switch' context in /home/main.php on line 7
```

you can use `trigger_error("\ncannot input number", E_USER_ERROR);`

Try the following code :

```
<?php 

function paint($room="office",$color="red")
{
if (is_int($room))
    {
   trigger_error("\ncannot input number", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
else{
return "\nthe color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
}

echo paint();
echo paint("bedroom","blue");
echo paint("kitchen",null);
echo paint(2,4);  //i want to give message "cannot input number"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems.

- `$var = integer` is an assignment, not a comparision. Since `integer` is neither a reserved word nor a defined constant, it will be converted into a string `'integer'` throwing a warning. This will be handled as fatal error in future PHP versions. Use the *identical operator* `===` for comparisions.
- You cannot check for types by `$var === typename`. There are functions to achieve this. `is_int($var)` checks if a variable is of the type integer.
- The `break` statement may be used in loops and switch constructs only.
- `else; return "";` does not return conditionally. The `else` branch is empty. You can have if-else-constructs without codeblocks. The next statement is executed conditionally. If it is a block, then everything within the block is conditionally. If it is a semicolon `;`, then it actually is an empty statement.

This is your function translated:

```
function paint($room = 'office', $color = 'red')
{
  // always true since non-empty strings evaluate to true in boolean context 
  if ($room = 'integer')
  {
    echo "Cannot input number"; /* break; is illegal here */
  }
  else
  {

  }

  // this is executed always
  return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

You probably wanted to do:

```
function paint($room = 'office', $color = 'red')
{
  if (is_int($room))
  {
    echo "Cannot input number";
    return '';
  }

  return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

The problem with this is, that integers are not the actual problem but complex data types not providing a propper string representation. You should use type hints instead.

```
declare( strict_types = 1);

function paint(string $room = 'office', string $color = 'red') : string
{
  return "the color of the {$room} is {$color}.<br />";
}
```

If you declare `strict_types`, passing arguments to and from functions will not implicitly change types.